# how to force rabbitmq to start automatically when my pc is rebooted

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

well the subject says it all. My rabbitmq server doesn't start automatically when i reboot my Win7 machine. Well it works when I start the server with the "rabbitmq-server" command but it's kind of annoying to do this whenever I reboot my machine.
It all started when I uninstalled the service in order to add a rabbitmq.config file. I had to uninstall and install the service because and I quote from the rabbitmq website  "Windows service users will need to re-install the service after adding or removing a configuration file".
Do you guys have any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: Which RMQ version are using ? Did you try to set `Automatic Delayed start` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a Windows Service.  Make sure it is set to "automatic".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by unistalling and installing the service, this time i set up the ErlangHome and RabbitMQ home before installing and it worked just fine .
Thank's guys!